# Does astaxanthin help prevent or heal a tendinopathy?

Tags: tendinopathy, treatment, tendons

{1} claims that [astaxanthin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astaxanthin):

> Use
>   of natural astaxanthin may suggest that daily use can help alleviate pain associated with Tennis
>   Elbow, and increase mobility

This study doesn't seem to have been published in a serious peer-reviewed venue, and I couldn't find any independent study (independent = not sponsored by some astaxanthin seller). I found 2 sponsored studies {2,3} but {2} didn't focus on tendon injuries and I couldn't access {3}.

Does astaxanthin help prevent or heal a tendinopathy?

---

References:

- {1} Effect of daily use of natural astaxanthin on symptoms associated with Tennis Elbow (lateral humeral epicondylitis). Gene A. Spiller, PhD, CNS, Antonella Dewell, MS, RD, Sally Chaves, RN, Zaga Rakidzich, Health Research & Studies Center, Los Altos, CA. https://www.cyanotech.com/pdfs/bioastin/batl65.pdf  ([mirror](https://archive.org/details/effectofdailyuseofnaturalastaxanthinonsymptomsassociatedwithtenniselbow))
- {2} Capelli, Bob, Usha Jenkins, and Gerald R. Cysewski. "Role of astaxanthin in sports nutrition." In Nutrition and Enhanced Sports Performance, pp. 465-471. Academic Press, 2013. https://doi.org/10.1016/B978-0-12-396454-0.00048-5
- {3} Capelli, B., and G. Cysewski. "Natural Astaxanthin: The World’s Best Kept Health Secret." (2013). https://www.researchgate.net/publication/325055058_NATURAL_ASTAXANTHIN_The_World's_Best_Kept_Health_Secret

Answer (score 5):

Source 3 is a book sponsered by Cyanotech Corporation claiming beneficial effects for the human health using Astaxanthin. The author is employee of Cyanotech Corporation.
There is a small chapter regarding beneficial effects of Astaxanthin for the tennis elbow, but is is only referring to source 1.

I did not find anymore studies referring to the effects of using Astaxanthin in the treatment of tennis elbow. But there is a [study](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.cyanotech.com/pdfs/bioastin/batl18.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjBpZz92fvjAhXBwsQBHSu5DM0QFjACegQIARAB&usg=AOvVaw03Lg12cq8x4NKKAxHroM0y&cshid=1565556981743)(1) (sponsered by Cyanotech Corporation) regarding carpal tunnel syndrome claiming a beneficial effect of Astaxanthin while there is another [one](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3280376/#__ffn_sectitle)(2) stating that there is no significant effect.

The European Food Saftey Authorizy gave their scientific opinion regarding health claims [here](http://www.efsa.europa.eu/en/efsajournal/pub/1253)(3):

> In addition, two unpublished reports on the effects of astaxanthin in the relief of pain and the improvement of performance in patients with carpal tunnel syndrome (Nir and Spiller, 2002a) and with tennis elbow (Spiller et al., 2006), and one intervention in patients with rheumatoid arthritis were 
>   presented to support the claimed effect (Nir and Spiller, 2002b). The Panel notes that the three studies above are pilot single-centre, double-blind placebo-controlled parallel studies conducted with a product containing high oleic safflower oil, Haematococcus extract, lutein, vitamin A, vitamin E, gelatine and rosemary oil in addition to astaxanthin, and therefore no conclusions can be drawn from these studies on the food that is the subject of the health claim, astaxanthin, in relation to the claimed 
>   effect. 
>   The Panel concludes that a cause and effect relationship has not been established between the 
>   consumption of astaxanthin and the maintenance of normal joints, tendons or connective tissue.

So there is no evidence available supporting the use of Astaxanthin for the treatment of tennis elbow

References:

(1)

BioAstin, a natural astaxanthin from microalge helps relieve pain and improves performance in patients with carpal tunnel syndrome
 https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.cyanotech.com/pdfs/bioastin/batl18.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjBpZz92fvjAhXBwsQBHSu5DM0QFjACegQIARAB&usg=AOvVaw03Lg12cq8x4NKKAxHroM0y&cshid=1565556981743

(2)

A blinded placebo-controlled randomized trial on the use of astaxanthin as an adjunct to splinting in the treatment of carpal tunnel syndrome
 https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3280376/#__ffn_sectitle

(3)

Scientific Opinion on the substantiation of health claims related to 
astaxanthin
 http://www.efsa.europa.eu/en/efsajournal/pub/1253